# Getting Worklight project having errors while deploying

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

when I right click and run --> build all and deploy getting error like

[Project name] contains errors.

But the same project was working earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open problems tab in the eclipse 
Right click and delete all the errors and warnings
Delete the bin folder contents and remove the projects from server.
clean the project and restart the server.
Build and deploy the project.